# Vim put cursor in the middle of screen after buffer switch

Tags: vim

When I switch buffer and then go back to it (when I get back to any buffer that was previously opened), cursor is placed in the middle of the screen, loosing previous screen position (e.g. cursor at top of the screen). Maybe this is the normal behaviour of vim, but is there any way to fix this?

This problem happens when I use :bn and bp: to switch buffers. However this behaviour does not happen when switching between tabs which is really strange.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch buffer"? `:next`, `:bnext`, `CTRL-W k`, `gt`, something else? I'm trying to reproduce your issue but can't find the command you're using.

Comment: I am using :bn and :bp to go back and forth between buffers.

Comment: What you want is the default behavior. Please post your vimrc.

Comment: I tried loading vim without the .vimrc, and the behaviour persists. I am currently using version 7.3 under linux.

Comment: Did you install any plugins recently?

Comment: After running Vim without .vimrc and plugins, I decided to uninstall and delete /usr/share/vim folder and reinstalling Vim. The problem is now solve, so I reckon there was probably some file editing in the Vim folder program which altered the normal behaviour of Vim. Thank you all and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_scrolling_when_switch_buffers

```
" When switching buffers, preserve window view.
if v:version >= 700
   au BufLeave * if !&diff | let b:winview = winsaveview() | endif
   au BufEnter * if exists('b:winview') && !&diff | call   winrestview(b:winview) | endif
endif
```